# Need to print Dom path when clicked anywhere in a page using only JS

Tags: javascript

Need to print the all parentnodes nodename in order when we clicked anywhere in a html page. for eg if i clicked somewhere (inside the html page) paragraph. i need output as HTML>Body>Div>p>(clicked)
I need to use only simple javascript for this. I tried the below code. but i can't get answer. help me to findout,

```
script.js

document.body.onclick = function(e){
var x= e.parentNode.nodeName;
console.log(x); 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the event target, you just climb up the `parentNode` tree, prepending the tag names, e.g.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.body.addEventListener('click', climbNodes);
}

function climbNodes(e){
  var node = e.target;
  var ancestors = node.tagName;
  while (node.parentNode && node.parentNode.tagName) {
    node = node.parentNode;
    ancestors = node.tagName + '>' + ancestors;
  }
  console.log(ancestors);
}
```

```html
<div>Click here
  <div>or here
    <p>
      <span>or here</span>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>or here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let els = document.getElementsByTagName('*')
let nodes = []

for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let element = this
    nodes = []
    while (element.nodeName !== 'HTML') {

      // Add element to nodes
      nodes.push(element)

      // Set element equal to parent element
      element = element.parentNode
    }
  })
}
```